# Angular.js organization with global variable or not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working on an angular app and know there's a few ways to architect it.

The first would be to create a global namespace such as:

```
var App = angular.module('app', []);
```

Then, for example with controllers, I would do:

```
App.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

The other method (from what I can tell) is to modularize my controllers, such as:

```
angular.module('App', ['home']);

angular.module('home').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

The other method, looks like this:

```
angular.module('App'), ['App.controllers']);

angular.module('App.controllers').controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

Is there any benefit to any of these or is there a best practice or common style that's being adapted in the angular community?

Thank you!

Comment: I think it is a matter of personnal choice. In my case, I prefer to use the third way, so I have a module for my app, my controllers, my services, my directives, my filters, etc... Maybe it could be useful if you think of reusing certain parts in other apps.

Comment: @dave here you can find some AngularJS guidelines https://github.com/mgechev/angularjs-style-guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, having dealt with a few large projects where I have used AngularJS, here are a few things off the top of my head:

1. End result wise, there is no difference between the three approaches you have outlined
2. Watch out with 2 and 3, you might run into errors with AngularJS complaining that you don't have the a module called 'home'. As it turns out, calling `angular.module('home')` tells AngularJS to look up a module called home that has already been created. Calling `angular.module('home', [])` tells it to create a new module called home. Subtle, but major difference.

That said, I would highly recommend following the later approach **if** you are looking at developing components that you want to reuse across all the applications you build. Say for example, you are building some web apps, and you have developed your own UI components like datepicker, carousel, etc. Now, since you don't want to code them again and again, then you can put them inside a module (say "Common.components").

You can then **export** just the JS files as a library that you can include in all your projects, without having to copy paste code, or extract it from the bowels of your giant application.

This gives you nice modular, reusable pieces that can play nice across a variety of apps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the are any specific benefits in either of the methods. I don't even think there is any difference between them. As of now, I'm unaware of any Angular.js codes style "guidelines". It is a matter of readability and personal taste.
Here are a couple of links I found useful (Angular docs are not perfect, to put it politely):

1. [8 Tips for Angular.js Beginners](http://vxtindia.com/blog/8-tips-for-angular-js-beginners/)
2. [AngularJS Tips and Tricks](http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED)